# Where/whom did Madara donate his right eye?

Tags: naruto

[image]

It's mentioned in chapter 602 page 17 that Madara gave away his eye to someone... But it's not mentioned whom. He also says that his eyes aren't his own (he could be referring to his brother's eyes). Most of the Q&A discussions I came across on Google say that it's donated to Nagato! It's mentioned in Wiki too, but I haven't come across any anime episode or manga chapter stating it. Has it ever been mentioned anywhere else, to whom did he donate his eyes (or at least his right eye)?

Comment: Would someone show courtesy by writing reason for downvotes? or will it be the least thing I expect? –

Comment: It's probably because your question is one big mess. The title asks where he lost his eye, then your question is asking who he donated it to. It is kind of confusing at first sight, but I managed to understand it fine.

Comment: Thaks for that ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Madara did in fact give his eyes to Nagato. (Chapter 606 Page 16 ~)

[image]

Comment: Is there any link for reference? (I saw it in Wiki but that won't be considered as a proof)

Comment: Never mind I found one

Comment: I corrected my previous answer as well as posted the picture of proof.

Comment: the real question is where did Madara get his new left eye which was a sharingan. he gave both of his rinnegan eyes to Nagato, but which uchiha lost an eye to give him one

Answer (score 2):

In chapter 658, it's said that "Right eye returns to rightful owner". Which proves it was transplanted to nagato. Although doesn't specify when/how.

Comment: It's Nagato's eye, which was taken by Obito, from Obito to Madara! The phrase "returned Rightful owner" proves it was it's own eye returned back to him ..

Comment: @R.J, you are talking about left eye! His right eye slot was empty. (before death as well as after revival)

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' Not sure what the confusion is. In my post, it is revealed that both of Madara's real eyes are in Nagato.

Comment: actually madara didn't have eyes when he was revived with the rinne tensei, zetsu retrieved his right eye from nagato's corpse and obito still has his left eye, once he dies from using the rinne tensei then black zetsu will bring madara his left eye from obito's body, hope this helps, evidence is from chapter 656 and above the reason he has the rinnegan while he's an edo tensei is because you can be customized almost as when nagato was revived he had both his rinnegan even though obito had taken one, he didn't have either original eyes when he died.   http://www.mangabee.com/Naruto/656/18/

Comment: he only had a replacement but for whatever reason he wasnt revived with that eye, hope that helped

Answer (score -1):

Yup, Sort of, U see, Nagato is an Uzumaki, and they are connected to Senju, and Madara has Uchiha blood circulated to his Rinnegan Which he got from implanting Hashirama cells) and then, he gave his right eye (Which had Uchiha blood) to Nagato, who had Senju blood, thus awakening 2 Rinnegans for Nagato and Madara is left with his left Sharingan/Rinnegan. U may be wondering, how does Obito have his right eye, that's because he unconsciously transported the right side of his face to Kamui, then unconsciously got it back, also, Obito's left face is scarred bcz of the amateur eye transplanting by Rin (DUH SHE LIKE 12 YRS OLD)

Comment: None of the stuff about Obito is relevant to the question at all.